# Modules not found in VS code. I installed pyautogui and some other modules using pip but my code does not run

Tags: python, module

I get the message :

> File "c:\Users\oussa\Desktop\python_not_wroking\nothing.py", line 1, in 
> import pyautogui as pe
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'

I set up venv and changed the interpreter to the python.exe in venv. The problem is that it did not run before in VS code, even without venv and I know I installed everything correctly because everything runs fine when I run my code through IDLE in the desktop

Comment: Did you install package `pyautogui` to your venv ? My recommendation is [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/)

Comment: using `py -m pip install pyautogui` ? yes.
Though it says that requirement is already satisfied

Comment: It is likely you have 2 Python installations and `pip` is installing in the one but VScode is using the other. To find out where `pip` is installing:  `pip --version`.